# How to connect 2 smartphones via WiFi Direct ADB to get the 1st to control applications run on the 2nd?

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, wifi-direct

How to connect 2 smartphones via USB to get the 1st to control applications running on the 2nd?

I don't mean the connection to be limited to screen mirroring or off-lione file transfer only.

I need 1st smartphone to control applications running on 2nd smartphone in interactive mode, exactly as I can control applications run on Android board connected to PC via USB cable.

Ok, OTG and host mode supported since modern smartphones intended to work in parallel.

Another related question: [How to start an application using android ADB tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools)

A couple of examples:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n
com.android.settings/.Settings
```

will launch Settings, and

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n
com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity
```

will launch the Browser. If you want to point the Browser at a particular page, do this

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n
com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity http://www.google.co.uk
```

*From: [How to run (not only install) an android application using .apk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109234/how-to-run-not-only-install-an-android-application-using-apk-file)*

follow-up 2

connected my 5.0.2 Android smartphone to 4.0.2 Android tablet via microUSB2USB cable inserted into OTG USB2micxroUSB to get microUSB on both hands Enabled usb debugging on both devices, run adb daemon on port 5038 on smartphone. None device connected, no TCPIP established In programming mode I need to select debugging app on tablet: one suggested by default is: com.android.partnerbrowsercustomizations.example other option is None Should I select the above or install one another, called ???

Comment: great related question, comments and answers with examples
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools

"We can as well start an application by knowing application type and feeding it with data:

adb shell am start -d "file:///sdcard/sample.3gp" -t "video/3gp" -a android.intent.action.VIEW

Comment: If an application  can be started and run via adb, fed with data and if such application run generates output data, is it possible to fork and redirect that data to usb port for viewing, processing, saving on the 1st smartphone running adb ?

Comment: 1st please don't post links to search engines because every body will get different search results. If you want to link to an external page include the link to the final page. 2nd please don't use comments for just adding info. Instead just edit the question.

Comment: @iknow thank you for your edit help

"adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings"

BTW
not sure why select & C&P generated extra signs

"adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings"

it must be MS Windows > Linux ASCII string conversion

Comment: If there any manual in htmlized / Javascript form, listing syntax to run every native Android app via ADB USB

How to gues the following :

"adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n
com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity http://www.google.co.uk

or 

 adb shell input tap x y

can broadcasted output from app run via ADB USB be redirected (fork) to USB interface for postprocessing by a script to keep interactive communication via USB continued ?

how to get to more advanced examples or learning course on video ?

Comment: I have worked really hard for the last 2 weeks to get to the following conclusion:

 I need to connect 2 smartphones via WiFi Direct only, no usb cable, no wifi router, since I need to use usb slot for charging.

There are tens of WiFi ADB applications in Play store  but many described as wireless ADB still requiring usb cable.
My search for WiFi only ADB still generates many discussions on SE, many answers, many comments, not listing the right solution, not requiring root access.

So I need to test 20+ apps one by one to get the answer

Comment: The USB cable is required for initially enabling wireless adb. On a unrooted device there is AFAIK no other way to enable adb wireless. After enabling you can remove the USB connection and adb wireless stays enabled until you reboot the device.

Comment: @Robert thank you for your kind explanation
Just got 2 bluetooth keyboards to make life easier, one is mini-bluetooth keyboard, supporting MS Windows, another is ultrathin keyboard cover for iPad (bluetooth )
Unfortunately, they fail to support Press Enter as Linux Return key in Android shell emulator, so I have to look for remapping solution (how to emulate Linux Return key press)
I have a number of 4.2, 5.2 smartphones and tablets, so hope to start tests with adb very soon

Comment: @Robert connected my 5.0.2 Android smartphone to 4.0.2 Android tablet via microUSB2USB cable inserted into OTG USB2micxroUSB to get microUSB on both hands
Enable usb debugging on both devices, run adb daemon on port 5038 on smartphone
None device connected, no TCPIP established  In programming mode I need to select debugging app on tablet: one suggested by default is:
com.android.partnerbrowsercustomizations.example
other option is None
Should I select the above or install one another, called ???

Comment: So the adb connection works? The debugging app setting is AFAIR useless as it just stops the app if it starts until a debugger connects.

Comment: @Robert 
My smartphone fails to connect to tablet via usb cable, can connect to PC but fails to detect usb mouse connected via OTG cable, the same for USB pendrive, so microUSB port in my smartphone seems not to support connecting to another Android device.
I will try powered usb hub tomorrow.
In the meantime I charge my another Android 4.2 10 inch 3G tablet, unused for 2 years for Tablet2Tablet connection via usb cable.

changed connection mode to PC via usb cable to tethering  - connection established with PC . smartphone 2 tablet failed to connect via usb cable

Answer (score 0):

This looks like part of your answer: install the Termux app, and then [adb to run within it](https://github.com/MasterDevX/Termux-ADB). I have not tried this yet.